# Why does the V/Hz ratio of a motor affect the magnetic field strength?

Tags: induction-motor, magnetic-flux

When the frequency is increased whilst keeping the voltage constant, the magnetic field strength is going to weaken... I don't understand why and what actually happens that causes the field strength to drop.

If anybody has an information on this I'd appreciate some clarity on the matter.

Comment: A hint: consider how that affects the current, given that motors are inductive

Comment: Moving rotor generates almost the same voltage as driver (BEMF) and thus with no load current is only 5%~10% of load current.  Surge current at stall is V+/ DCR of coil can be 5~10x due to DCR/Zcoil(f)  at full loaded RPM.  Thus to flatten torque = current vs RPM, V is increased with f.

Comment: current thru an inductor, which your coils are, is I = 1/L * integral(V*dT). This means faster frequency gives a smaller dT, and the peak current is reduced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the equivalent circuit for one phase of an induction motor shown below. The current, \$Im\$ in the magnetizing inductance \$Xm\$ determines the stator magnetic field strength. For a simple approximation, we can assume that \$Xs = 0\$ and everything else in the circuit except \$Xm\$ is infinite. We can then say that \$Im = \frac{V}{Xm}\$

Since \$Xm = 2*Pi*f*Lm\$, we can say that $$Im = \frac{V}{f}*\frac{1}{(2*Pi*Lm)}$$.

If we include all of the other components in the analysis, we will see that they have some influence, but the simple approximation shows pretty well what is happening.

[image]
Diagram adapted from Malcom Barnes "Practical Variable Speed Drives and Power Electronics"